# How to show all rows by default in JQuery DataTable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, datatables

Does anybody know how to show all rows by default in jQuery datatable?

I have tried this code, but it only shows 10 rows by default.

```
   $("#adminProducts").dataTable({
        "aLengthMenu": [100]
    });
```

Answer (score 268, accepted):

Use:

```
$('#example').dataTable({
    aLengthMenu: [
        [25, 50, 100, 200, -1],
        [25, 50, 100, 200, "All"]
    ],
    iDisplayLength: -1
});
```

Or if using 1.10+

```
$('#example').dataTable({
    paging: false
});
```

Comment: Or `"paging": false` if you use [DataTables 1.10 new API](https://datatables.net/reference/option/paging).

Comment: Or `<table data-display-length='-1'>` if you want to use DOM options (DataTables 1.10+, see https://datatables.net/manual/data/orthogonal-data#HTML-5).

Comment: The meat of this very correct answer is iDisplayLength: -1

Answer (score 17):

The option you should use is iDisplayLength:

```
$('#adminProducts').dataTable({
  'iDisplayLength': 100
});
```

Answer (score 6):

```
$('#table').DataTable({
   "lengthMenu": [ [5, 10, 25, 50, -1], [5, 10, 25, 50, "All"] ]
});
```

Answer (score 3):

It will Load by default all entries.

```
$('#example').dataTable({
    aLengthMenu: [
        [25, 50, 100, 200, -1],
        [25, 50, 100, 200, "All"]
    ],
    iDisplayLength: -1
});
```

Or if using 1.10+

```
$('#example').dataTable({
    paging: false
});
```

If you want to load by default 25 not all do this.

```
$('#example').dataTable({
    aLengthMenu: [
        [25, 50, 100, 200, -1],
        [25, 50, 100, 200, "All"]
    ],
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using DataTables 1.10+ you can use the data-* attribute in your `<table>` tag  `data-page-length="-1"`

This assumes you have "-1" defined in your datatable default configuration, such as below

```
$.extend(true, $.fn.dataTable.defaults, { 
    lengthMenu: [[10, 25, 50, 250, -1], [10, 25, 50, 250, "All"]]
});
```

Your javascript becomes simply `$("table").DataTables();` and you're able to customize the display for every table within in the HTML;  IE. if you have second, smaller table in the same page that should be limited to 10 rows, `<table data-page-length="10">`

Comment: perfecto mondo! The best answer given the secnario where a global DataTables() initialization is done

Answer (score 2):

This one works for me:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]]
      } );
    } );
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the entire functional javascript for your .html file

```
<!--- javascript -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#sortable').dataTable({
        'iDisplayLength': 100
    })})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

use 'fnDrawCallback'

```
  $('#dataTable').dataTable({
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "fnInitComplete": function(){
            $('.display_results').show();
        },
        "fnDrawCallback": function() {
            $('.def').click(function(){
                var msg = $(this).next().text();
                $('.messages').messageBox()//Custom Dialog
            });
        }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to download the bootstrap-table.min.js and make some modification to it..

- If you download the bootstrap-table.min.js, just open it, and try to find "pageList:[10,"
  make it as "pageList:[10,15,20,25,50,100,"All"]" make sure that "All" written as this.
- Default page size can be changed as well from the same line "pageSize:10" you can change it as pageSize:"All".
- Other options can be modified as well.
- Don't forget to include it or linked to new place after completed your modification.

I hope it is clear and easy enough to be done.

Comment: I tried all the above answers and it didn't work.. Just follow the above Instructions.