# jQuery Datatables: iDisplayLength set to -1 to show all rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatable

I use jQuery Datatables and want to listen a Table with all my entries via ajax from a server. Everything works perfectly. I mean, i get the data and can show them in the table. I got only one problem. I want to show all rows/entries at once. I've googled and all say, that i just have to set the iDisplayLength to -1. But if I do that, i got only 1 entrie/row(Showing 1 of 1 of totally 50 entries). Any idea what i'm doing wrong? This is my code to initialize the table:

```
var oTable = $("#roles").dataTable({
    "bServerSide"       : true,
    "sAjaxSource"       : "/data",
    "iDisplayLength"    : -1,
    "aoSearchCols:"     ["sSearch" : initiator], null, null, null, null, null, null],
    "fnServerParams"    : function(aoData){
                        aoData.push({"name": "sLDAPQuery", "value": "roles"});
    }
});
```

edit: It works, if I set iDisplayLength for example to 1'000, but what if I get more than 1'000 rows?

Comment: What about this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9443773/how-to-show-all-rows-by-default-in-jquery-datatable ?

Comment: @Shinosha He just add aLengthMenu, and i don't need that. In the next step, i want to disable Pagination("bPaginatie": false).

Answer (score 2):

I think you first get how many records you are having in the database than dynamically add the length dynamically using [fnLengthChange](http://datatables.net/plug-ins/api#fnLengthChange)

Please click on fnLengthChange. It will show you the example. May it helps you