# Enable DataTables pagination dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am facing a problem where my columns don't show the proper values, apart from for the rows that are loaded by default(10). Is there any way in Datatable to disable pagination i.e. load all rows at once and then immediately re-enable pagination. I need it as the number of rows are too many.

This is how I am initializing the Data table:

```
$('#rTable').DataTable({
    paging: false
});
```

After it is initialized, I want to enable paging in rTable. Any way to do this?

Comment: Some code sample, or a JSFiddle would be nice to help us.

Comment: Made the edit in the question

Comment: From a datatables developer: `The short answer is that you cannot alter initialisation options after the table has been initialised, unless there is an API available for it. You need to reinitialise the table.` [Source](https://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/16373/enable-disable-features-after-initializing-the-table)

Comment: There must be something wrong with your data or code logic. In client-side processing mode DataTables already does what you need, i.e. load all rows at once but display `10` records by default by adding pagination control. You don't need to enable/disable pagination for this to work.

Answer (score -2):

You can try setting an *All* option in the length menu or set *paging* as false (from 1.10+).

Eg.

```
$('#example').dataTable({
    aLengthMenu: [
      [25, 50, 100, 200, -1],
      [25, 50, 100, 200, "All"]
    ],
    iDisplayLength: -1
});
```

Or

```
$('#example').dataTable({
    paging: false
});
```

Checkout this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12727548/354307)