# How to remove pagination of Multifilter Datatables

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, datatable, pagination

I'm currently developing a Human Resource systems for a company. I'm using PHP5 and MySQL as my every go tools. I have came across a table tool called "Multi Filter Datatables", which enables me to query/filter data without going through mysql query, anyways the data from the tables are from the mysql tables from the backend.. I implemented it without any problems, got it working. Now I just got one question, how can I remove pagination? I would like to display all data because when I'm printing the table, it only shows page 1. It only captures the current built of the table.. I have researched some answers here on Stack, but I can't seem to get it work.. Here is the script..Thanks in advance..

```js
 <script type="text/javascript" class="init">
    
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {

        initComplete: function () {
           
            this.api().columns().every( function () {

                var column = this;
                var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
                    .appendTo( $(column.footer()).empty() )
                    .on( 'change', function () {
                        var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                            $(this).val()
                        );
 
                        column
                            .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                            .draw();
                    } );
 
                column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                    select.append( '<option>'+d+'</option>' )
                } );
            } 
            );
        }
    } );
} );



    </script>
```

Comment: Are you referring to this jQuery plugin? https://datatables.net/

Comment: @Terminus yes sir.

Comment: There's a way to display all table rows by adding an "All" option to the `show # results` select. How to do that depends on the version; which version are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 1.10.12.. I saw some code like this

$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#Grid_Id').dataTable({
                "bPaginate": false
            });
        });

Where should I put the code.. I tried but it kept messing with the table

Comment: See this question answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9443773/how-to-show-all-rows-by-default-in-jquery-datatable If it answers your question, you might as well close this one as a duplicate.

Comment: Thank you for referring, but one quick question, uhm where will I put "paging false" in the script that I provided above.

Comment: It's a configuration option for datatables. You have to add it to the object you pass when you initialize the datatable. So `$('#example').DataTable( { paging: false, initComplete... rest of code... });`

Comment: @Terminus, thank you so much, will now close the question with a duplicate. You just saved my life man