# How to override scripts of jquery datatable API?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, datatables

I am working on codeigniter and I have implemented jquery datatable api in my page. Everything works fine. And as you know, by default the api gives us a dropdown above the table where we can select no of records to show and we also have the search functionality. Now, what I want is, when the user gives input to the search box and the table is showing the search results. Instead of limited no of results, I want to show all records at once. How can I do that ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show all rows by default in JQuery DataTable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9443773/how-to-show-all-rows-by-default-in-jquery-datatable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to

1. Include a `-1` value in the `lengthMenu` so all rows is selectable
2. When the table is being filtered, that is when `search.dt` is broadcasted, set lengthMenus `-1` option as selected and trigger a `change` event
3. Set a flag on the dataTable object to prevent the event being triggered over and over

Example :

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
  lengthMenu: [[10, -1], [10, "All"]]
})  

$('#example').on('search.dt', function(e, api) {
  if (!api._allForced) {
    $('.dataTables_length select option[value=-1]').prop('selected', true);
    $('.dataTables_length select').change();
    api._allForced = true    
  }
})
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/stmo9w8w/**

Comment: Okay, so with this code I am able to show all records when input is given to the search box. But when I clear the input on the search box, the dropdown value doesn't go back to it's default value ? Thank you for the response

Comment: @RabinLama, "_But when I clear the input on the search box, the dropdown value doesn't go back to it's default value ?_" , yes - I only answer the question. It should be a nobrainer to reset the dropdown when the search term is empty.

Answer (score 0):

https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/length_menu.html

> It is possible to easily customise the options shown in the length
>   menu (by default at the top left of the table) using the lengthMenu
>   initialisation option.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]]
    } );
} );
```

*first result on google :*

[How to show all rows by default in JQuery DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9443773/how-to-show-all-rows-by-default-in-jquery-datatable) :

Comment: Why are you copying someone else's answer to a duplicate question?  Flag this as a duplicate.  Don't post the duplicate answer.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Will try it. And where can I find more of these (i.e. aLengthMenu, iDisplayLength, paging)